# Powershell, how to check if spuser object is user or group?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script which is fixing some corrupted userprofiles. But the results are also groups. I would like to skip the groups and fix only the users. How can I check if the spuser object is a user or group in Powershell?

```
$webApp = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication]::Lookup("http://portal.myCompany.net") 

foreach ($site in $webApp.Sites) 
{ 
     foreach($webSite in $site.AllWebs)
     {
        $siteUrl = $site.Url
        $webUrl = $webSite.Url
        write-host $siteUrl
        write-host $webUrl

        $allCoruptedUsers = Get-SPUser -Limit All –Web  $webUrl | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName –like "myDomain*"} 

        # get all users from project portal
        foreach ($user in $allCoruptedUsers)
        {    
            #TODO: CHECK IF THIS $USER OBJECT IS A USER AND NOT A GROUP
            write-host " - fix displayname" $user.LoginName -ForeGroundColor Green
            Set-SPUser -Identity $user -Web $webUrl -SyncFromAD   
        }

        write-host ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the type of the object:

```
if($user.GetType().FullName.Equals("Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser"))
{
}
```

Comment: I still get errors: Set-SPUser : Cannot get the full name or e-mail address of user domainname\adGroup

Comment: Look like you have imported to sharepoint AD groups as users. So the easiest way is to put Set-SPUser into try/catch block. try{Set-SPUser -Identity $user -Web $webUrl -SyncFromAD}catch{write-host 'well, it's not a user:' $user.LoginName}